# How to refresh listView to after closing the dialog ?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a layout that opens the dialog, and after entering the dialog, the user selects ok/cancel. I want to refresh the listView to requery the data

Here's my layout that would open the dialog:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SchoolActivity.this, InsertSchool.class);
                update();
                startActivity(myIntent);
                updateList();
            }
        });
        update();
        cursor.requery();
        String[] from = new String[]{Database.KEY_ID2, Database.KSCHOOL, Database.KSCHOOLCODE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rid, R.id.rt1, R.id.rt2};

        cursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_school, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

After clicking that button, I want to refresh the listView. Here's the dialog (I think refreshing is going to be done here on the ok & cancel buttons).

```
            ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(InsertSchool.this, SchoolActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        update();
        mySQLiteAdapter = new Database(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueSchoolAll();

        ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String data1 = ie1.getText().toString();
                String data2 = ie2.getText().toString();
                mySQLiteAdapter.insertSchool(data1, data2);
                updateList();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(InsertSchool.this, SchoolActivity.class);
                update();
                startActivity(myIntent);

                mySQLiteAdapter.close();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: use pull to refresh library..https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fchrisbanes%2FAndroid-PullToRefresh&ei=jk0MU7ryE4mRrAelyoCIDA&usg=AFQjCNFfDp36h1omRJIIVOtNBUQaFjigYw&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bmk&cad=rja

Comment: Please provide `update()` and `updateList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh a `listView` you should call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your list's adapter. When calling that method is up to you... maybe inside your `onClickListener`.

Comment: It should. Maybe you have to put it at the end of your `updateList()` method. Although I don't know what it looks like at this moment

Comment: just write a content provider and everything will be up to date automatically (follow notepad tutorial)

Comment: @super-qua I really appreciate your thoughts, I did try moving it in many ways but didnt work :/ ... maybe I'll just create a refresh button than to refreshing it automatically...

Comment: @pskink what do you mean?

Comment: @user3214807 i mean http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html, in particular exercise 1

Answer (score 1):

I simply use this technique : in the main activity put this

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  refreshData();  
}
```

as soon the AlertDialog is dismissed, it calls therefreshData() method that refreshs the ListView

Comment: This method is quite risky it works ok, but it repeats refreshData() insane so better wouldnt be a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.onCancelListener` in your dialog to know when ur dialog get cancel. 
Then u can referesh ur data